# Pellet + Transitivity + Reason + OWL-API

Tags: jena, owl, ontology, owl-api, pellet

I have problem using Pellet in inferencing transitive object property Similarto. I have individual A Similarto B and individual B Similarto C. I want to use Pellet in OWL API or use Jena to get the individual group A, B, C, But I cannot figure out the code to do the reasoning in OWL API.

I have already loaded the ontology in OWL API, and is there an example code of inferencing a group of individuals that were connected with the same transitive property?

Comment: Or this can not be done by Pellet? Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is instructed from Ignazio Palmisano:

If there is no current solution from pellet, we can write our own.

- Select your starting point, i.e., the first individual in your 
  transitive chain
- Retrieve all fillers for the property you're after
- For each filler, retrieve all fillers as in the previous step
- Take care of avoiding cycles

(The reason to have both a set and a list is to be able to iterate in 
a predictable way while adding elements, and retain fast containment 
checks - at the cost of a little memory)

```
 OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
            Set<OWLNamedIndividual> found= new HashSet<>(); 
            List<OWLNamedIndividual> list= new ArrayList<>();
            List<OWLNamedIndividual> SeaIcelist= new ArrayList<>();
            PrefixManager pm = new DefaultPrefixManager("http://www.semanticweb.org/SeaIceOntology#");

            OWLNamedIndividual root = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(":thickness", pm);
            OWLObjectProperty p = factory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI
                    .create("http://www.semanticweb.org/SeaIceOntology#similarTo")); 
            OWLReasoner r= new StructuralReasonerFactory().createNonBufferingReasoner(loadMODIS);

            found.add(root); 
            list.add(root); 


            while(i < list.size()){ 
                for(Node<OWLNamedIndividual> ind:r.getObjectPropertyValues
                        (list.get(i), (OWLObjectPropertyExpression)p)){ 
                    for(OWLNamedIndividual nind:ind){
                        if(found.add(nind)){
                            list.add(nind);
                            /* select specific individuals to the SeaIcelist */
                            for(OWLClassExpression ex : nind.getTypes(loadMODIS)) {
                                while(ex.asOWLClass().getSuperClasses(loadMODIS).iterator().hasNext()){
                                    for(OWLClassExpression cl:ex.asOWLClass().getSuperClasses(loadMODIS)) {
                                        if (cl.equals(factory.getOWLClass
                                                (IRI.create("http://www.semanticweb.org/SeaIceOntology#EarthScienceProperty"))) ){
                                            SeaIcelist.add(nind);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    ex = ex.asOWLClass().getSuperClasses(loadMODIS).iterator().next();
                                }
                             }
                            /* select specific individuals to the SeaIcelist */
                        }
                    }
                }
                i ++;
            }

            for (int j = 1; j < i; j ++){
                System.out.println("These are all the terms which has similar meanings." + list.get(j).toStringID());
            }

            int size = SeaIcelist.size();
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j ++){
                System.out.println("These are all the standard terms which has similar meanings." + SeaIcelist.get(j).toStringID());
            }
```